# Set default container layout for i3 window manager

Tags: i3-window-manager

I am using the i3 window manager for a few days now and I am amazed how well everything works. :)

The only thing I am still looking for is how to change the default container layout to tabbed/stacked.

I found a post in a forum from 2010 where somebody states, that [this was not possible back then](http://infra.in.zekjur.net/archives/i3-discuss/2010-February/000007.html).

Does anybody know, if there is a way to accomplish changing the default container layout now, or if is still not possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

possible for now :)
in `.i3/config` add line

`workspace_layout <default|stacking|tabbed>`

eg. `workspace_layout tabbed` for windows open in tabbed mode in workspaces

from http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_layout_mode_for_new_containers

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Answers that are just links are not acceptable.

Comment: @G-Man the answer was *below* link. I've reorder lines to give answer first (and add where to add that line), and then a link.

Comment: Correct answer still in '17

Comment: If you want to make a different layout for just one application, use something like this: `for_window [class="Firefox"] layout tabbed` or use [this script](https://github.com/i3/i3/blob/next/contrib/per-workspace-layout.pl) to apply a layout per workspace.